# SwiftUI = Pass Value from UIViewController to UIViewControllerRepresentable - Coordinator?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Missing some key point here, and have tried a variety of ways to solve this. Most resources use existing ViewControllers such as MapKit or UIPicker. In this case, I have a custom ViewController from which I want to return a UIImage.

I have a UIViewControllerRepresentable which presents a UIViewController.

The ViewController creates an image. How do I return the image so that it can be used in the SwiftUI view?

The closest I can seem to get is to set up a UIViewControllerRepresentable with a Coordinator (is that needed?):

```
struct CameraPreviewView: UIViewControllerRepresentable  {
 @Binding var photoTaken: UIImage

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
  return Coordinator(photoTaken: $photoTaken)
 }

 class Coordinator: NSObject {
  @Binding var photoTaken: UIImage
  init(photoTaken: Binding<UIImage>) {
   _photoTaken = photoTaken
  }
 }

 func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CameraPreviewView>) -> CameraViewController {
 let cameraViewController = CameraViewController()
 return cameraViewController
 }
... 
}
```

But how do you then create 'activate' the Coordinator so that the ViewController returns the image?

```
final class CameraViewController : UIViewController {
 // Clearly something goes here, but what?
 //var photoTaken: UIImage
 // @Binding photoTaken: UIImage

 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
 }
 // A bunch of camera code is here
}

extension CameraViewController: BBMetalCameraPhotoDelegate {
 func camera(_ camera: BBMetalCamera, didOutput texture: MTLTexture) {
 // This is the image we want returned to SwiftUI 
 imageView.image = filter.filteredImage(with: texture.bb_image!)
 ..
 }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I stole a page from UITextField and added a notification and a listener.

Now, my Coordinator works as follows:

```
func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
 Coordinator(self)
}

class Coordinator: NSObject {
 var parent: CameraPreviewView
 var photoFromCoordinator = UIImage(named: "test")!

 init(_ viewController: CameraPreviewView) {
  self.parent = viewController
  super.init()

  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "imageDidChange"), object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main){(notification) in
   print("notice received")
   if let image = notification.userInfo?["image"] as? UIImage {
    self.photoFromCoordinator = image
   }
  }
 }
}
```

And I fire off the UIImage from my Controller:

```
...
let imageDataDict:[String: UIImage] = ["image": finalImage]
let nc = NotificationCenter.default
nc.post(name: Notification.Name("imageDidChange"), object: nil, userInfo: imageDataDict)
...
```

So, I'm closer. The notification is 'firing' within my coordinator.

But now, how to extract the image within the SwiftUI view?

So far:

```
struct ContentView: View {
 @State var photoTaken: UIImage?

 var body: some View {
    //Image(photoTaken)
```

Does @State var photoTaken receive data from the Coordinator? If yes, how can it be rendered in the view?